# How to fix the error "403 Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: Sources.xz" during apt-get update?

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, proxy, apt-cacher

I am using `apt-cacher` to do `apt-get update` on the client machine. However, the setup is not working - I get the following error on doing `apt-get update`:

```
W: The repository 'http://<local_repo_IP>:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
E: Failed to fetch http://<local_repo_IP>:3142/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/xenial.main/source/Sources
403 Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: Sources.xz
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried setting up proxy in different places, trying one after the other when it doesn't work:

1. `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf`

   `Acquire::http::proxy "<local_repo_IP>:3142";`
2. `sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90-apt-proxy.conf`

   `Acquire::http::proxy "<local_repo_IP>:3142";`

Suggested [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/3078) is to edit the regular expression in `/etc/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.conf`:

```
package_files_regexp = (?:^[-+.a-z0-9]+_(?:\d:)?[-+.~a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_?[-a-z0-9]+\.(?:u|d)?deb|\.dsc|\.tar(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)|\.diff\.gz)|\.rpm|index\.db-.+\.gz|\.jigdo|\.template)$
```

But I have not tried this yet for fear of royally screwing up my system.

Please suggest how I can make `apt-get update` work.

Comment: It looks like it's a known issue on the server side (i.e. whatever machine is running the `apt-cacher` caching proxy that you are connecting to): see for example [apt-cacher: missing support for xz-compressed indices](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=809431) - it's apparently fixed in apt-cacher version 1.7.12 however the version in 16.04 appears to be 1.7.11

Comment: @steeldriver I see. So, would it be possible to upgrade `apt-cacher` to v1.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 without breaking anything?